# Does scikit learn include a Naive Bayes classifier with continuous inputs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bayesian

Is there anything in scikit learn that can help me with the following?

I need a Bayesian network that is capable of taking continuous valued inputs and training against continuous valued targets. I then want to feed in new, previously unseen continuous inputs and receive estimates of the target values. Preferably with a way to measure confidence of the predictions. (PDFs perhaps?)

I am uncertain whether this would be considered a Naive Bayes Classifier or not.

I keep looking at GaussianNB but I just cannot see how it could be used in this way.

I'd like one that support "independence of irrelevant alternatives"

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about **regression**, not classification. Naive Bayes **Classifier** is not a regression model. Check out numerous [scikit-learn's regressors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning). IN particular, your could be interested in [**Bayesian Ridge Regression**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html#sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge).

Comment: +1 for analyzing the problem as regression, but note that Bayesian ridge regression has nothing in particular to do with naive Bayes (because naive Bayes is **not** a Bayesian model).

Comment: I am aware that it has nothing to do with each other, it is just a probabilistic interpretation/approach to the regularization, nothing more.